# WSO2 End User authentication using OKTA

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-api-manager, okta

We have a web application portal currently running on **Apache web server**.The end users are available in **OKTA identity** with MFA enabled.

Front end: *Angular SPA*

Back end: *Spring micro services*

There is a requirement to set up the WSO2 API manager and do integrate with OKTA service.

> 1. WSO2 API manager must be integrated with OKTA to perform **end user** authentication using OKTA.

> 2. WSO2 API Manager publisher and developer portal shall be still using *local user authentication* and local user store, as access is not exposed to end user.

`In our understanding,the work flow should be like WSO2 API manager must validate the API request (protected via okta access token), redirect end user to OKTA login via SAML or OIDC, then end user logins via OKTA portal, OKTA redirects the end user back to WSO2 api manager with tokens`

We are trying to do a POC, and found tutorials about

a.Configuring OKTA as IDP for API manager, but we don't want publisher or devportal to be IDP enabled, but only end user authentication.

b.About writing Custom Auth Handlers, but not clear how the re-direction should be handled with handlers.

c. About integrating OKTA as key manager, how ever we need SAML redirection and let user login via OKTA portal.

Nothing found conclusive for our use case.

> 1. Is this feasible with WSO2 API manager ?

> 2. Or should the OKTA integration to be moved to Apache Web server?

> 3. How should WSO2 API manager be made aware of OKTA token validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the steps performed to achieve the same.

- Integrate the Angular Application directly with OKTA. Link [here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-spa/angular/before-you-begin/).
- Add OKTA as a key manager in the WSO2 APIM via admin console.Link [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-okta-connector/).

- Publish the Application API with OKTA as allowed Key manager, rest of the WSO2 features must use resident key managers.
- In devPortal, create application and configure OKTA with client id and keep client secret empty.
- Subscribe to the required APIs.
- From front end application, login to OKTA and generate access token pass it along with each API request.
- WSO2 OKTA key manager will validate the token successfully and route the requests.